# Casting received uint8_t buffer to struct in C

Tags: c, serial-communication

I have to handle the communication between a computer running a program written in Python and microcontroller using C code. The protocol struct is designed to prevent padding using `uin32_t` for all fields except the `value` which is restricted to be either `int` or `double`. It looks something like this:

```c
struct head {
    #define CMD_SET 1
    #define CMD_GET 2
    uint32_t cmd;
    uint32_t err;

    #define TYPE_INT    1
    #define TYPE_DOUBLE 2
    uint32_t type;
};

struct frame {
    struct head *head;
    void *val;
};
```

If I initially get the raw bytes in a `uint8_t` buffer and the buffer was made to comply with the struct layout above, can I cast to and from this buffer to `struct head` and to `void *val`?

I have tried the code below and it seems to be working but I am afraid that it might invoke UB. Is the code below safe? If not, what techniques should I use to handle this process? Use `memcpy`? Maybe `#pragma pack`?

```c
// Example:

uint8_t buf[sizeof(struct head) * 2] = {0}; // Make the buffer big enough

void process_cmd(uint8_t *buf)
{   
    struct frame frame = {0};
    
    frame.head = (struct frame *)buf; // UB?
    frame.val = frame.head + 1

    if (frame.head->cmd == CMD_SET) {
        if (frame.head->type == TYPE_INT) {
            do_work_with_int(*(int *)frame.val); // UB?
        } else if (frame.head->type == TYPE_DOUBLE) {
            do_work_with_dobule(*(double *)frame.val); // UB?
        }
    } else if (frame.head->cmd == CMD_GET) {
        if (frame.head->type == TYPE_INT) {
            int val = 1;
            memcpy(frame.val, &val, sizeof(val));
        } else if (frame.head->type == TYPE_DOUBLE) {
            double val = 2.0;
            memcpy(frame.val, &val, sizeof(val));
        }
    } else {
        frame.err = 1;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    uart_read(uart_hdlr, buf, sizeof(buf));

    process_cmd(buf);

    uart_send(uart_hdlr, buf, sizeof(buf));
}
```

Comment: Either `memcpy` or using a union to type pun are safe (and should compile to the exact same assembly code)

Comment: No, it is not safe. Aliasing an array of `uint8_t` through a structure type (or most other types) is not defined by the C standard. And, even if your C implementation extends the standard to support aliasing, you have not ensure the buffer has the required alignment.

Comment: One way to do it properly is to define a union that contains the structure(s) you expect to receive and an array of `uint8_t`. Then pass the array to the read routine that fills the array with the raw bytes. Then you can access the other union members. Using `frame.val` the way you do also has problems.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ok I see. Thanks. For reference, should packing the struct with #pragma pack(1) take care of “buffer has the required alignment”?

Comment: @Blue No.......

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Why not? The alignment requirements of the structure members would be reduced to 1. So the alignment requirements would be satisfied. It does not fix the aliasing problem, though.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `#pragma pack` is not defined by the C spec. 
 Various implementation do different things.  [Exmaple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pack?view=msvc-170) with its "even get a hardware-generated exception for unaligned access", thus obliging a `memcpy()` to save/set values.